# scala: creating a new object by having its name?

Tags: scala

Consider a class with the following definition:

```
package packageName 

case class ClassName[T <: AnyRef](
  name: String,
  sensor: T => String,
  range: Option[List[String]]
)(implicit val tag: ClassTag[T]) extends SomeOtherClass[T, String] {
   // some stuff here 
}
```

In this definition, does `packageName.className$$anon$2` refer to the `sensor` function? Why the following operation give me `java.lang.InstantiationException`?

```
val clazz: Class[_] = Class.forName("packageName.ClassName$$anon$2")
var instance = clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: To your first question: No, because `sensor` is a constructor parameter, not a function expression.

Comment: Does the `InstantiationException` have a message?

Comment: `newInstance` calls the no-arg constructor, which will not work with your case class.

Comment: @ChrisMartin so `$$anon$2` is referring to the 2nd function definition in the body of the class?

Comment: I have no idea. I just know it's not `sensor` because that isn't the kind of thing that is represented in the bytecode as a class.